# How can i add a search to a reveal.js presentation?

Tags: javascript, search, presentation, reveal.js

How can i add a search to a reveal.js presentation ?
There is a search.js file available under plugins but i'm not sure how to use it.
Please help me to set this up. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To include the search plugin, you can add an entry to the dependencies array in the initialization object (this is at the bottom of the [index.html file](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/index.html#L381) in the repo):

```
Reveal.initialize({
  dependencies: [
    { src: 'plugin/search/search.js', async: true },
  ],
});
```

Comment: Dependencies has been deprecated as of reveal.js 4.0.0 but left in for backwards compatibility, see
https://revealjs.com/plugins/#dependencies